# AWS Cognito on custom domain not implementing correctly /.well-known/openid-configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, openid

I'm not an expert but seems like one of the OpenID requirements is to have a /.well-known/openid-configuration endpoint.

Seems like Cognito is implementing this well as long as you don't use custom domain, e.g. point your browser to the URL below and you get a properly defined openid config JSON.

> https://cognito-idp.{your region}.amazonaws.com/{your pool ID}/.well-known/openid-configuration

Now, if you use a custom domain try pointing your browser to the URL below, and you will see there is nothing but an error message:

> https://{your poolname}.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

This is an issue because other apps/framework/library that rely on OpenID standards fail when trying to connect to a Cognito user pool.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a custom domain doesn't change the issuer (`iss` claim in your tokens) and therefore the discovery URI is unchanged.

Your configured domain will be properly reflected in the configuration document (`/.well-known/openid-configuration`) and clients supporting discovery will be configured with your custom endpoints (authorization, userinfo and token).